# PCL can't find header file

Tags: ros, point-cloud-library, catkin

```
    /home/ubuntu/emvs_ws/src/rpg_emvs/mapper_emvs/src/realtime.cpp:25:62: fatal error: pcl/registration/impl/incremental_registration.hpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
rpg_emvs/mapper_emvs/CMakeFiles/realtime_emvs.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'rpg_emvs/mapper_emvs/CMakeFiles/realtime_emvs.dir/src/realtime.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [rpg_emvs/mapper_emvs/CMakeFiles/realtime_emvs.dir/src/realtime.cpp.o] Error 1
```

I'm getting this error after catkin_make

Theses are the includes in realtime.cpp

```
#include <pcl/registration/incremental_registration.h>
#include <pcl/registration/icp.h>
```

CMakeLists.txt file

```
project(mapper_emvs)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)

find_package(catkin_simple REQUIRED)
catkin_simple(ALL_DEPS_REQUIRED)

set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE RelWithDebInfo) # Release, RelWithDebInfo
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-O3 -fopenmp -std=c++11 ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")

## Generate dynamic reconfigure parameters in the 'cfg' folder
##generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options(
##  cfg/EMVSCfg.cfg
##)

set(HEADERS
  include/mapper_emvs/mapper_emvs.hpp
  include/mapper_emvs/data_loading.hpp
  include/mapper_emvs/depth_vector.hpp
  include/mapper_emvs/trajectory.hpp
  include/mapper_emvs/geometry_utils.hpp
  include/mapper_emvs/median_filtering.hpp
)

set(SOURCES
  src/mapper_emvs.cpp
  src/data_loading.cpp
  src/median_filtering.cpp
)

option(DEFINE_USE_INVERSE_DEPTH "Use linear spacing in inverse depth (if OFF, will use linear spacing in depth)" ON)
if(DEFINE_USE_INVERSE_DEPTH)
    add_definitions(-DUSE_INVERSE_DEPTH)
endif(DEFINE_USE_INVERSE_DEPTH)

cs_add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS})

# Executables
################################################################################

cs_add_executable(run_emvs src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(run_emvs ${PROJECT_NAME})

cs_add_executable(realtime_emvs src/realtime.cpp)
add_dependencies(realtime_emvs ${PROJECT_NAME}_gencfg)
target_link_libraries(realtime_emvs ${PROJECT_NAME})

################################################################################
cs_install()
cs_export()
```

Note that I did Catkin_make not catkin build, I don;t know if this makes a difference.

I'm asked to add more details, so please ignore this line :)

Comment: Can you share your CMakeLists.txt

Comment: I added CMakeLIsts.txt

Answer (score 0):

You need to add PCL library in your CMakeLists.txt file as follows:

```
    project(mapper_emvs)
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)

    find_package(catkin_simple REQUIRED)
    
    # Adding PCL lib
    find_package(PCL REQUIRED)
    # Setting include, lib directories and definitions 
    include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS} )
    add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS} )

    catkin_simple(ALL_DEPS_REQUIRED)

    set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE RelWithDebInfo) # Release, RelWithDebInfo
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-O3 -fopenmp -std=c++11 ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
        
    ## Generate dynamic reconfigure parameters in the 'cfg' folder
    ##generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options(
    ##  cfg/EMVSCfg.cfg
    ##)

    set(HEADERS
        include/mapper_emvs/mapper_emvs.hpp
        include/mapper_emvs/data_loading.hpp
        include/mapper_emvs/depth_vector.hpp
        include/mapper_emvs/trajectory.hpp
        include/mapper_emvs/geometry_utils.hpp
        include/mapper_emvs/median_filtering.hpp
    )
        
    set(SOURCES
        src/mapper_emvs.cpp
        src/data_loading.cpp
        src/median_filtering.cpp
    )
        
    option(DEFINE_USE_INVERSE_DEPTH "Use linear spacing in inverse depth (if OFF, will use linear spacing in depth)" ON)
    if(DEFINE_USE_INVERSE_DEPTH)
        add_definitions(-DUSE_INVERSE_DEPTH)
    endif(DEFINE_USE_INVERSE_DEPTH)
        
    cs_add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS})

    # Executables
    ################################################################################

    cs_add_executable(run_emvs src/main.cpp)
    target_link_libraries(run_emvs ${PROJECT_NAME} ${PCL_LIBRARIES})

    cs_add_executable(realtime_emvs src/realtime.cpp)
    add_dependencies(realtime_emvs ${PROJECT_NAME}_gencfg)
    target_link_libraries(realtime_emvs ${PROJECT_NAME} ${PCL_LIBRARIES})

    ################################################################################
    cs_install()
    cs_export()
```

**Note:** Hope you installed PCL lib. Besides,
I added `${PCL_LIBRARIES}` into `target_link_libraries`. I hope it will work this way, if you are getting some errors, try adding `${PCL_LIBRARIES}` into  cs_add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS} ${PCL_LIBRARIES}). Please let us know if get errors after applying these changes.